# value of echo not appear.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

```
<?php
include("db/dbconnect2.php");

$noMyKid1 = $_GET['noMyKid'];

echo $noMyKid1;

$sql= "SELECT namaAnak,noSijilLahir
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE a.noMyKid='noMyKid1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or @error_die("Query failed : $sql " . mysql_error());

echo $noMyKid;
echo $namaAnak;
echo $noSijilLahir;
?>
```

I run this coding, but the output just appear for

```
echo $noMyKid1;,echo $noMyKid;
```

Why `echo $namaAnak;and echo $noSijilLahir;` not appear?

Comment: In the SQL query you probably meant to say `WHERE a.noMyKid='$noMyKid1'` (you should add the $ if you are using the variable). Also, you run the query, which goes into `$result`, but you don't do anything with the result.  It does not auto-populate variables from your query. You need to fetch the values first.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause they are not defined. Also, you've forgotten `$` sign(I guess, if there is `a.noMyKid='noMyKid1'` then sorry):

```
$sql= "SELECT namaAnak,noSijilLahir
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE a.noMyKid='$noMyKid1'";
```

And to fetch you result set:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['namaAnak'];
   echo $row['noSijilLahir'];
}
```

Comment: yep, he/she did not fetch the data from the query result.

Comment: thank you so much. I realize the fetch data before i read the comment. but i forgot to put $ sign.LOL~. thank you for helping..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are echoing empty variable without initialized any value on it:

This is full code may be working for you:

```
<?php
include("db/dbconnect2.php");

$noMyKid1 = $_GET['noMyKid'];

echo $noMyKid1;

$sql= "SELECT namaAnak,noSijilLahir
FROM mohon a 
INNER JOIN tblstatus_tak_lengkap b on a.noMyKid=b.nomykid 
WHERE a.noMyKid='$noMyKid1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or @error_die("Query failed : $sql " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['namaAnak'];
   echo $row['noSijilLahir'];
}
?>
```

And you have forgotten `$` sign on your query string

```
WHERE a.noMyKid='$noMyKid1'";
```